# PHP 5.6 Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, ssl, composer-php, magento2

I am using SSL on my website.
Earlier it was working fine but now it is not working.
I am getting issue.

```
Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/etc/pki/tls/certs) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/home:/tmp:/usr) in /home/xx/public_html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 914
```

Any solution?

Comment: are you using magento?

Comment: @user10089632  Yes I am using magento 2

Comment: if you add the proper tag, hopefully you'll get a more precise answers

Comment: is there someone else who may have change the configuration? could this be a connection issue?

Comment: @user10089632 I wish I know about it.

Comment: I think to add code in index.php file error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); so remove that code or comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is in the error message.
Either add the path to the certs in
the config, or move the certs to one of the allowed paths.